How to run multiple websocket client connections?
I have a Django service (let's call it the "main" service) running an HTTP server & a WebSocket server using django-channels. I also have a bunch of other django services(call them target services) wanting to connect to the websocket channels exposed by the main service. Each service needs to establish multiple websocket connections with the main service, and send/receive messages as long the connection is not closed by the main service.
Here are some sample connection URLs:
URL1 = "wss://main-service.com/ws-connection/1"
URL2 = "wss://main-service.com/ws-connection/2"
URL3 = "wss://main-service.com/ws-connection/3"

This list of URLs is not known in advance; the main service sends us a mini payload which is used to generate the URL at runtime, and connection is established.
The target service needs to have the ability to maintain thousands of websocket connections (serving as stateful connections) & it also needs to expose an HTTP API to serve direct requests.
So far, I have got the target service API running as Django project, and a basic websocket client, and the two look like this:
Websocket client:
from abc import abstractmethod
from websocket import WebSocketApp as _WebSocketApp


class WebSocketApp(_WebSocketApp):
    def __init__(self, url=None):
            super(WebSocketApp, self).__init__(url=url, on_open=self._on_open on_message=self._on_message, on_error=self._on_error, on_close=self._on_close)
        self.logger = get_logger()  # TODO: set level
        self.logger.debug(f"Websocket adapter is ready")

    @abstractmethod
    def _on_open(self, ws):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _on_message(self, ws, message):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _on_error(self, ws, error):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _on_close(self, ws, code, message):
        pass


Django view:
from adapters.web_socket import WebSocketApp
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from server.celery import app


@app.task()
def ws_handler(conversation_id):
    # TODO: standardise
    url = f"wss://main-service.com/connections/{id}"
    socket = WebSocketApp(url=url)
    socket.run_forever()


@api_view(["POST"])
def index(request):
    _id = request.data["_id"]
    ws_handler.delay(id=_id)
        # NOTE: verify connection via caching  


This works well, but the Django server gets blocked as soon as a new websocket connection is established. For the time being, I got around that by sending websocket connection requests to a Celery worker. I know it's not going end well as Celery is just going to eat my server, and I will soon be out of worker threads, but it allows me to keep my Django server free.
Instead, I would really like to turn this into an elegant async websocket client, so that I can run multiple websocket connections per thread, preferably thousands of them. I would still like to keep the celery worker to do the data processing work for me, but I wouldn't want to burden it with websocket management, so I'd like the websocket stuff to happen outside the Celery & the Django server process
Here's what I have put together so far:
import pdb
import asyncio
import websockets
import json


class WebSocketAdapter:
    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.uri = uri
        self.websocket = None

    async def connect(self):
        try:
            self.websocket = await websockets.connect(self.uri)
            await self.on_connect()
            await self.receive_messages()
            await self.receive_messages()
        except Exception as e:
            await self.on_error(e)

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.websocket.close()

    async def send_message(self, message):
        if self.websocket is not None:
            await self.websocket.send(json.dumps(message))
            print("Message Sent")
        else:
            print("WebSocket connecion is not established")

    async def receive_messages(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = await self.websocket.recv()
                await self.on_message((message))
                # asyncio.create_task(self.on_message(await self.websocket.recv()))
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                await self.on_close()
                break
            except Exception as e:
                await self.on_error(e)

    async def on_connect(self):
        print("Connected to WebSocket server.")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f"Received message from server: {message}")

    async def on_error(self, error):
        print("WebSocket error:", error)

    async def on_close(self):
        print("WebSocket connection closed.")


async def main(url):
    websocket_adapter = WebSocketAdapter(url)
    await websocket_adapter.connect()
    # NOTE: following line of code is never executed :(
    await websocket_adapter.send_message("Message from client.")



async def test():

    urls = [
        "ws://localhost:8765/conversations/1",
        "ws://localhost:8765/conversations/2",
        "ws://localhost:8765/conversations/3",
    ]
    tasks = [main(url) for url in urls]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


# Run the event loop
asyncio.run(test())
# asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
# pdb.set_trace()
        

It seems to allow me to run multiple connections, but I'm not able to send/receive messages after the initial handshake, the code gets blocked at the receive_message method inside the adapter. Plus I cannot send messages outside the adapter after the connection is established, which also means the control is never returned to the caller, i.e. Django server
I had a simple websocket adapter which was synchronous and worked really well with callbacks, but with asyncio I have to build coroutines. How do I send the control back, how do I entertain new connection requests, and how do I test this thing on my local?
I would basically like the ability to receive connection request through an HTTP endpoint, establish a websocket connection in background, and continue receiving new requests, i.e I should be able to initialise many websocket client objects, with configurable callbacks, and just use them as I please.

Why to use websockets to transfer messages between the apps, you can use AMQP Message broker like RabbitMQ to transfer these messages.

It's basically a chat application, I do have a message broker in place, but it's not used to transfer chat messages per se, but more to generate signals within the system. I'd like to do this with websocket to provide a persistent peer-to-peer communication, and eventually turn this into a real-time system.
